# getting spefic values from JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, regex, ajax, openlayers-3

I am getting the data from ajax call in javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:URL,

    headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
    async: false,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
        result=data;
}
```

We are getting the response in this manner:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "totalFeatures": 3,
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "Site_view.5b59c3a5-bc04-4707-93e7",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        [174877.4813, 130159.3695],
                        [174991.5857, 130162.2884],
                        [175085.7881, 130172.9028],
                        [175204.6689, 130195.7236],
                        [175205.9957, 130192.274],
                        [175084.4613, 130170.7799],
                        [174989.7282, 130158.8387],
                        [174877.4813, 130159.3695]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    [
                        [175130.0918, 130397.2857],
                        [175152.5814, 130316.5877],
                        [174960.7581, 130303.3585],
                        [175130.0918, 130397.2857]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "geometry_name": "geometry",
        "properties": {
            "id": 24636,
            "name": "test CA 24 05-10-2017",
            "organisationId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxx",
            "parentId": null,
            "reference": null,
            "siteStartDate": null,
            "siteEndDate": null,
            "Expr1": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
            "creationDate": "2018-06-05T11:26:41.673Z",
            "modificationDate": "2018-09-20T12:37:30.257Z",
            "siteId": "f3f0fe94-eec7-4ff0-8a12-5c6dfc67b38f",
            "type": "https://xxxxxx/cl/xxxxx/constructionZone",
            "validityEndDate": null,
            "Expr3": "2018-06-05T11:26:41.673Z",
            "nomBase": "ZZZ_Powalco_Test",
            "nomParent": null,
            "status": "Inscription",
            "idPowalco": "18007495",
            "bbox": [174877.4813, 130158.8387, 175205.9957, 130397.2857]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "Site_view.9e7bf413-ae67-4a40-9825-3c69ad4bdbfc",
        "geometry": null,
        "geometry_name": "geometry",
        "properties": {
            "id": 24638,
            "name": "test CA 24 05-10-2017",
            "organisationId": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "parentId": null,
            "reference": null,
            "siteStartDate": null,
            "siteEndDate": null,
            "Expr1": "f3f0fe94-eec7-4ff0-8a12-5c6dfc67b38f",
            "creationDate": "2018-06-05T11:26:45.116Z",
            "modificationDate": "2018-06-05T11:26:45.116Z",
            "siteId": "f3f0fe94-eec7-4ff0-8a12-5c6dfc67b38f",
            "type": "https://xxx/xx/SiteType/ZCCC",
            "validityEndDate": null,
            "Expr3": null,
            "nomBase": "ZZZ_Powalco_Test",
            "nomParent": null,
            "status": "Inscription",
            "idPowalco": "xxx"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "Site_view.xxxxxx",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        [174865.8055, 130168.1263],
                        [175247.3917, 130213.768],
                        [175250.8413, 130192.5393],
                        [175109.405, 130153.7969],
                        [174866.867, 130142.9172],
                        [174865.8055, 130168.1263]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    [
                        [174960.7581, 130303.3585],
                        [175130.0918, 130397.2857],
                        [175152.5814, 130316.5877],
                        [174960.7581, 130303.3585]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "geometry_name": "geometry",
        "properties": {
            "id": 24637,
            "name": "test CA 24 05-10-2017",
            "organisationId": "3dd8aedd-cb82-4fa4-b932-2046ea7b7251",
            "parentId": null,
            "reference": null,
            "siteStartDate": null,
            "siteEndDate": null,
            "Expr1": "f3f0fe94-eec7-4ff0-8a12-5c6dfc67b38f",
            "creationDate": "2018-06-05T11:26:41.674Z",
            "modificationDate": "2018-09-20T12:37:30.257Z",
            "siteId": "f3f0fe94-eec7-4ff0-8a12-5c6dfc67b38f",
            "type": "https://xxxxxx/cl/SiteType/perimeterZone",
            "validityEndDate": null,
            "Expr3": "2018-06-05T11:26:41.674Z",
            "nomBase": "ZZZ_Powalco_Test",
            "nomParent": null,
            "status": "Inscription",
            "idPowalco": "18007495",
            "bbox": [174865.8055, 130142.9172, 175250.8413, 130397.2857]
        }
    }],
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"
        }
    },
    "bbox": [174865.8055, 130142.9172, 175250.8413, 130397.2857]
}
```

So here my requirement is to extract the "type" values from the data.

```
"type":"https://xxxxxx/cl/SiteType/perimeterZone"
"type":"https://xxxxxx/cl/xxxxx/constructionZone"
```

Can we do it without using Regex.

FYI: We are using OpenLayers3.

Comment: What did you try? I think you shouldn't do it by regex.

Comment: Can you do it without using regex? Yes, you can.

Comment: You should really at least make an attempt at solving the problem yourself before asking for help.

Comment: @RockySims And how did you deduce that I haven't tried and posted the question?

Comment: @SubhranilSengupta because you haven't posted it. Sure that doesn't mean you haven't tried anything but a *very cursory glance* at this problem should have told you it's possible to do without regex by using bog standard JS ways of fetching values.

Comment: @SubhranilSengupta basically what vlaz said. When you post on stack overflow you should say what you've tried and your question doesn't talk about anything you've tried. Seeing what you've tried and hearing why it didn't work helps us answer your question (so we don't tell you to do what you've already tried and also to help illustrate what kind of solution you're going for).

Comment: @RockySims Thanks, I tried regex and some other methods to get the value, but failed. I will take care from the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing:

1. Parse the result.
2. Get specific data that you want.

```js
var jsonData = JSON.parse(result);

(jsonData.features).forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item.properties.type);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const types = data.features.map(feature => feature.properties.type);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data={
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "totalFeatures": 3,
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "Site_view.5b59c3a5-bc04-4707-93e7",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        [174877.4813, 130159.3695],
                        [174991.5857, 130162.2884],
                        [175085.7881, 130172.9028],
                        [175204.6689, 130195.7236],
                        [175205.9957, 130192.274],
                        [175084.4613, 130170.7799],
                        [174989.7282, 130158.8387],
                        [174877.4813, 130159.3695]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    [
                        [175130.0918, 130397.2857],
                        [175152.5814, 130316.5877],
                        [174960.7581, 130303.3585],
                        [175130.0918, 130397.2857]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "geometry_name": "geometry",
        "properties": {
            "id": 24636,
            "name": "test CA 24 05-10-2017",
            "organisationId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxx",
            "parentId": null,
            "reference": null,
            "siteStartDate": null,
            "siteEndDate": null,
            "Expr1": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
            "creationDate": "2018-06-05T11:26:41.673Z",
            "modificationDate": "2018-09-20T12:37:30.257Z",
            "siteId": "f3f0fe94-eec7-4ff0-8a12-5c6dfc67b38f",
            "type": "https://xxxxxx/cl/xxxxx/constructionZone",
            "validityEndDate": null,
            "Expr3": "2018-06-05T11:26:41.673Z",
            "nomBase": "ZZZ_Powalco_Test",
            "nomParent": null,
            "status": "Inscription",
            "idPowalco": "18007495",
            "bbox": [174877.4813, 130158.8387, 175205.9957, 130397.2857]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "Site_view.9e7bf413-ae67-4a40-9825-3c69ad4bdbfc",
        "geometry": null,
        "geometry_name": "geometry",
        "properties": {
            "id": 24638,
            "name": "test CA 24 05-10-2017",
            "organisationId": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "parentId": null,
            "reference": null,
            "siteStartDate": null,
            "siteEndDate": null,
            "Expr1": "f3f0fe94-eec7-4ff0-8a12-5c6dfc67b38f",
            "creationDate": "2018-06-05T11:26:45.116Z",
            "modificationDate": "2018-06-05T11:26:45.116Z",
            "siteId": "f3f0fe94-eec7-4ff0-8a12-5c6dfc67b38f",
            "type": "https://xxx/xx/SiteType/ZCCC",
            "validityEndDate": null,
            "Expr3": null,
            "nomBase": "ZZZ_Powalco_Test",
            "nomParent": null,
            "status": "Inscription",
            "idPowalco": "xxx"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "Site_view.xxxxxx",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        [174865.8055, 130168.1263],
                        [175247.3917, 130213.768],
                        [175250.8413, 130192.5393],
                        [175109.405, 130153.7969],
                        [174866.867, 130142.9172],
                        [174865.8055, 130168.1263]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    [
                        [174960.7581, 130303.3585],
                        [175130.0918, 130397.2857],
                        [175152.5814, 130316.5877],
                        [174960.7581, 130303.3585]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "geometry_name": "geometry",
        "properties": {
            "id": 24637,
            "name": "test CA 24 05-10-2017",
            "organisationId": "3dd8aedd-cb82-4fa4-b932-2046ea7b7251",
            "parentId": null,
            "reference": null,
            "siteStartDate": null,
            "siteEndDate": null,
            "Expr1": "f3f0fe94-eec7-4ff0-8a12-5c6dfc67b38f",
            "creationDate": "2018-06-05T11:26:41.674Z",
            "modificationDate": "2018-09-20T12:37:30.257Z",
            "siteId": "f3f0fe94-eec7-4ff0-8a12-5c6dfc67b38f",
            "type": "https://xxxxxx/cl/SiteType/perimeterZone",
            "validityEndDate": null,
            "Expr3": "2018-06-05T11:26:41.674Z",
            "nomBase": "ZZZ_Powalco_Test",
            "nomParent": null,
            "status": "Inscription",
            "idPowalco": "18007495",
            "bbox": [174865.8055, 130142.9172, 175250.8413, 130397.2857]
        }
    }],
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"
        }
    },
    "bbox": [174865.8055, 130142.9172, 175250.8413, 130397.2857]
};
data.features.map(feature => {
  console.log("Type : "+feature.properties.type);
});
```

Just iterate your data using map.